# Run JS / JQuery if CSS is supported

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modernizr

How can I run js / jquery if this CSS3 is supported.

I am already using modernizr, but how do I use it to detect support for this exact style and not one of the pre-build tests for features.

The CSS I need to check for support is:

```
@supports((-moz-font-feature-settings:"liga=1, dlig=1") or (-moz-font-feature-settings:"liga","dlig") or (-ms-font-feature-settings:"liga","dlig") or (-o-font-feature-settings:"liga","dlig") or (-webkit-font-feature-settings:"liga","dlig") or (font-feature-settings:"liga","dlig"){ //nothing in here }
```

If that is supported, then I need to run certain jQuery code. I can't do it inside the supports-query because what I need to do goes beyond applying styles and it something CSS can not do, only JS / jQuery.

Comment: This might be of some help https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/902

Answer (score 2):

Just add some unique CSS where you have `//nothing in here` and use JavaScript to detect whether the CSS is added or not.

```
@supports((-moz-font-feature-settings:"liga=1, dlig=1") 
or (-moz-font-feature-settings:"liga","dlig")
or (-ms-font-feature-settings:"liga","dlig")
or (-o-font-feature-settings:"liga","dlig") 
or (-webkit-font-feature-settings:"liga","dlig") 
or (font-feature-settings:"liga","dlig")
{ 
    body { z-index: 689; }
}
```

Then JavaScript:

```
if(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.zIndex === 689)
{
    // The CSS features are supported
} else {
    // Not supported
}
```

Comment: clever solution. nice thinking! I might try that.

Comment: I'm trying to implement it. The code makes sense and the idea, but I'm getting an error on my if condition. The error-console is saying can not read property style of type undefined. Here is the exact code I am using: `if(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.zIndex === 0){` on that line.

Comment: @IrfanMir The if should look like this: `if(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.zIndex && document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.zIndex === 0)` because if the CSS supports didn't add it then it won't exist, so you have to check for it first.

Comment: Or you could just put the whole thing in a try-catch block.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/902 to test for ligature support do this

```
if((Modernizr.prefixed("fontFeatureSettings")){
    //ligatures supported  
} else{
    //ligatures not supported
}
```

Comment: I can't use the Modernizr test because that test evaluates to true in iOS 6, when it is not supported. That is why I want to test for support for CSS's test for font-feature-settings. If that test evaluates to true then ligatures will be supported as most browsers that support at-supports will also supports ligatures in at-font-face.